# Error en instalación de symfony

Tags: symfony3

Seguí las instrucciones de instalación de symfony 3.2 de la website oficial (https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html). Cuando intento crear una app nueva, pasa lo siguiente:

```
    user@PC:/opt/lampp/htdocs$ symfony new NuevaApp
    /usr/bin/env: «php»: No existe el archivo o el directorio
    user@PC:/opt/lampp/htdocs$ php symfony new NuevaApp
    Could not open input file: symfony
    user@PC:/opt/lampp/htdocs$ whereis symfony
    symfony: /usr/local/bin/symfony
    user@PC:/opt/lampp/htdocs$ whereis php
    php: /opt/lampp/bin/php
```

Alguna ayuda? Saludos y gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Eso ocurre porque aun no tienes instalado el instalador de symfony, pero deberías hacerlo del otro modo usando composer.

primero descargas composer de aquí https://getcomposer.org/download/
Una vez descargado lo instalas como cualquier otro programa.

abres la consola y escribes esto:
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition my_project_name

recuerda que la parte final es la carpeta donde instalaras symfony "my_project_name" = la carpeta de tu proyecto y puedes llamarlo como quieras.

y Listo eso seria todo y ya podrías instalar symfony 3

Answer (score 0):

creo que lo primero que deberias probar es la instalación de PHP y Symfony.phar que hiciste sigue los siguientes pasos para el caso de symfony.phar:

1. sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
2. sudo curl -LsS https://symfony.com/installer -o /usr/local/bin/symfony
3. sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/symfony

Lo otro es que pruebes utilizando php -V si tienes correctamente instalado php y agregado en el path de tu sistema.

si todo va bien con estos dos consejos no debes tener problemas ejecutando el comando **symfony new NuevaApp**